# Closing a jQuery based tab on click itself and outside

Tags: jquery, html, css, tabs

[SOLVED IN THE ANSWER BELOW by dfsq]

So here goes the problem:

I am using a tab system very similar to this one http://jsfiddle.net/syahrasi/Us8uc/ and it works great on what I have already built on my application. But I'm really struggling to make two functions work within this tab system: clicking outside to close the current tab and clicking again on the a to close the tab (toggling, I guess).

```
$(".tabs-menu a").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().addClass("current");
    $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass("current");
    var tab = $(this).attr("href");
    $(".tab-content").not(tab).css("display", "none");
    $(tab).fadeIn();
});
```

I'd really appreciate some help here. This is really bugging me and I couldn't find any specific solution to this problem around here.

Comment: *"close the current tab"* What closed tab means? The first gets active?

Comment: @dfsq by that I mean closing the currently open tab by clicking on the "tabs-menu a", somewhat of a toggle. The a closes and opens the tab. Right now it's only opening.

Comment: Like this http://jsfiddle.net/Us8uc/954/ ?

Comment: @dfsq exactly like that, but there's one thing missing from the answer, the clicking outside to close.

Comment: For example using this http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-outside-events/examples/clickoutside/? I'm using it already, so if possible to do, would be perfect.

Comment: See my answer with the code for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can do it:

```
var $tabs = $(".tabs-menu a").click(function (event) {

    event.preventDefault();
    $(".tab-content").hide();

    var $parent = $(this).parent();

    if ($parent.is('.current')) {
        $parent.removeClass('current');
        $tabs.removeClass('current');
        return;
    }

    $tabs.removeClass('current');
    $parent.addClass("current");

    var tab = $(this).attr("href");
    $(tab).fadeIn();
}).parent();

$('body').click(function(e) {
    if (!$(e.target).closest('#tabs-container').length) {
        $tabs.filter('.current').find('a').click();
    }
});
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Us8uc/955/

Comment: Thank you very much. Fast and nicely implemented answer.